# No applicable constructor/method found when accessing each row in a Dataset in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run this simple code using Spark 2.1.1.

```
// Create the case classes for our domain
case class Department(id: String, name: String)
case class Employee(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, salary: Int)
case class DepartmentWithEmployees(id : Int, department: Department, employees: Vector[Employee])

// Create the Departments
val department1 = new Department("123456", "Computer Science")
val department2 = new Department("789012", "Mechanical Engineering")
val department3 = new Department("345678", "Theater and Drama")
val department4 = new Department("901234", "Indoor Recreation")

// Create the Employees
val employee1 = new Employee("michael", "armbrust", "no-reply@berkeley.edu", 100000)
val employee2 = new Employee("xiangrui", "meng", "no-reply@stanford.edu", 120000)
val employee3 = new Employee("matei", null, "no-reply@waterloo.edu", 140000)
val employee4 = new Employee(null, "wendell", "no-reply@princeton.edu", 160000)

// Create the DepartmentWithEmployees instances from Departments and Employees
val departmentWithEmployees1 = new DepartmentWithEmployees(1, department1, Vector(employee1, employee2))
val departmentWithEmployees2 = new DepartmentWithEmployees(2, department2, Vector(employee3, employee4))
val departmentWithEmployees3 = new DepartmentWithEmployees(3, department3, Vector(employee1, employee4))
val departmentWithEmployees4 = new DepartmentWithEmployees(4, department4, Vector(employee2, employee3))

val departmentsWithEmployeesSeq1 = Vector(departmentWithEmployees1, departmentWithEmployees2)

//converting to Dataset 
val df1 = departmentsWithEmployeesSeq1.toDF()
val ds1 = df1.as[DepartmentWithEmployees]
//try to access the objects
ds1.collect.foreach{
        x => println(x.id)
}
```

But getting the following error while trying to access the objects inside each row:

```
Name: java.lang.RuntimeException
Message: Error while decoding: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 503, Column 89: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "int, $line1910.$read$$iw$$iw$Department, scala.collection.Seq"; candidates are: "$line1912.$read$$iw$$iw$DepartmentWithEmployees(int, $line1910.$read$$iw$$iw$Department, scala.collection.immutable.Vector)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on Spark 2.3.0, It works fine.

Comment: That's not an answer, but runs fine on Databricks as well, 2.3.1